# Stripe rails integration by custom UI build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

How can I show the Saved Payment methods in form of a UI in my rails application using Stripe Payment gateway .

Comment: Is this question more about how to retrieve the PaymentMethods, or how to display them in your UI? To get this data, you can make the `Stripe::Customer.list_payment_methods` call[1] to get all saved PaymentMethods for a Customer.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/customer_list?lang=ruby

Comment: On how to display in form of UI on my rails app for future payments .